# C++ Create pointer array to all public static member functions inside header and then use it

Tags: c++, arrays, pointer-to-member

[Ubuntu 13.10]

I'm creating a class that contains a bunch of callback functions.  In my main program, I assign these callbacks to various nodes.  I would like to be able to do this in a loop, so I'm trying to create a static pointer array in the header class (no .cpp) that has all the addresses of its member functions.

I can't seem to work out the syntax to do this.

1) Below is my header defined class.  Am I initialising cbPointer the correct way?

```
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

typedef void (*FunctionPointer)(const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr &);

class myCallbacks {

public:


    static void cbEvent1(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg) {
            std::cout << "I heard: " << msg->data.c_str() << std::endl;
    }

    static void cbEvent2(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg) {
            std::cout << "I heard: " << msg->data.c_str() << std::endl;
    }

    constexpr static const FunctionPointer cbPointer[2] = {&myCallbacks::cbEvent1, &myCallbacks::cbEvent2};

};
```

Then in my main program, I'm assigning the callback like this:

```
for (int j=0; j<NO_CALLBACKS; j++) {
    subList[j] = (sNode[j])->subscribe(myCallbacks::cbPointer[j]);
}
```

The `subscribe` method has the following signature:

```
template<class M , class T >
subscribe (void(T::*fp)(M))
```

But I get a **link** error:  `undefined reference to myCallbacks::cbPointer`.  I've tried all kinds of variations of `subList[j] = (sNode[j])->subscribe(myCallbacks::cbPointer[j]);` but nothing seems to be working.

Would someone please help me with the right syntax?
*(Also, is it possible to create thet array in the header without spelling out each of the function names?)*

Comment: Have you defined `cbPointer` in a .cpp file other than just declaring it?

Comment: No, doing it all through the header file.

Comment: Defining data in header files is a bad idea because it can violate the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out how to get it done:

```
#ifndef MYCALLBACKS_H
#define MYCALLBACKS_H

#include "std_msgs/String.h"

typedef void (*FunctionPointer)(const std_msgs::String_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr &);

class myCallbacks {

public:


    static void cbEvent1(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg) {
            std::cout << "I heard: " << msg->data.c_str() << std::endl;
    }

    static void cbEvent2(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg) {
            std::cout << "I heard: " << msg->data.c_str() << std::endl;
    }

    static FunctionPointer cbPointer[];

}
FunctionPointer myCallbacks::cbPointer[] = {&myCallbacks::cbEvent1, &myCallbacks::cbEvent2};

#endif
```

Now I can reference the address of the member functions by using `myCallbacks::cbPointer[x]`.

Comment: By defining the array in your header, you risk violating the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). If your header file is ever included in multiple translation units (ie, by multiple .cpp files), then each translation unit will get a copy of the array, violating ODR. The correct way to do it is to have a separate .cpp file for the static data member definition, and leave only the declaration in the header file. Yes it's a little more verbose, but will save you headaches later.

Comment: Yes, I didn't include a #ifndef directive in the code, I will add it.

Comment: @SchighSchagh, ic.  Will this cause an error, or just make the executable larger?  (This header is used as a child of a larger object, and would not be included in anything else on its own.)  Your comments please?